# Why rails caches_actions uses wrong layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, layout

There is posts controller with index action in my app, it can respond with html and rss. I set it to be cached using memcached with `caches_action :index, :layout => false, …`, everything works fine for html, but when rss is already cached, then I get it wrapped into html layout application.html.haml, though I have rss layout application.rss.haml.

I understand that for rss it is better to use caches_page, but I would like to know why wrong type of layout is used. I use rails 3.0.7.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this too, `caches_action` doesn't respect formats and layouts correctly, so we had to do this:

```
caches_action :index, :layout => false, :if => Proc.new {|c| c.request.format.try(:html?)}
caches_action :index, :if => Proc.new {|c| c.request.format.try(:rss?)}
```

Basically having individual caches_action calls for each different format you wish to cache.